# How to calculate distance between two records

Tags: apex, soql, geolocation

I need to calculate distance between Lead and Account, but I get this error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void
>   GEOLOCATION(Decimal, Decimal)

My code:

```
for(Lead ld:[Select Id,City,State,SIC_Code_1__c,Latitude,Longitude from Lead where Id=:CurrentId ])
{
    Latitudes=ld.Latitude;
    Longtitudes=ld.Longitude;
}
if(Siccodes !=null && !Siccodes.isEmpty()){
    Temporary.clear();
    for (Opportunity opp:[Select Id,Name,StageName,Account.name,Number_of_Units__c,account.SIC_Code__c,Type,
                          Billing_City__c,Billing_State_Province__c,account.SIC_Industry_Name__c,
                          account.No_of_active_units__c,account.BillingLatitude,account.BillingLongitude from opportunity where account.SIC_Code__c 
                          LIKE :codes and StageName='Closed Won' ORDER BY account.No_of_active_units__c Desc NULLS LAST Limit 10])
    {
        if(opp.account.SIC_Code__c <> null)
        {
            Temporary.add(opp);
            Total = DISTANCE(GEOLOCATION(opp.account.BillingLatitude,opp.account.BillingLongitude),GEOLOCATION(Latitudes,Longtitudes), 'mi');
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DISTANCE & GEOLOCATION` are [SOQL Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_geolocate.htm), you can't use them in apex.

Thanks for your comment kurunve, so as [documented here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_system_Location.htm), this should work in Apex:

```
Location loc1 = Location.newInstance(28.635308,77.22496);
Location loc2 = Location.newInstance(37.7749295,-122.4194155);
Double dist = Location.getDistance(loc1, loc2, 'mi');
```

Comment: you can add that there is  **Schema.Location** class, that allow to do such a things in apex 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_system_Location.htm

Comment: Is there any possibility to use default Latitude and Longitude fields in apex to retrive distance.Because i have already billing location address & lead address .So, i need to provide distance between them

Comment: what do you mean by "default"? You are already using the standard fields like account.BillingLatitude

Comment: @Basti why i am getting null if i try to query Location loc1 = Location.newInstance(Latitudes,Longtitudes);
System.debug('Data in:'+loc1);
Location loc2 =Location.newInstance(opp.account.BillingLatitude,opp.account.BillingLongitude);
System.debug('Data in loc2:'+loc2);

Comment: debug all your variables, some of them might be empty?